# c++ In lambda function - error: invalid type argument in tbb::parallel_for

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda

New to tbb and lambdas in c++ and having compiler errors on the following code:

```
template <class ObjT, class Stepper>
class GroupStepper 
    : public Stepper {

public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ObjT> obj_ptr;

    void step () {

        tbb::parallel_for (blocked_range<int> (0, objs_.size ()),
                     [this] (const blocked_range<int>& r) {
        for (int i=r.begin (), e=r.end (); i<e; ++i) {
            Stepper::step (objs_[i], h_);
        }
        });
    };

private:

    std::vector<obj_ptr>&   objs_;
    scalar                  h_;
};
```

Compiling with gcc v. 4.5.1 I get the following errors:

```
In lambda function:

... error: invalid type argument

... error: invalid type argument
```

Both are referring to the input arguments to Stepper::step.  I'm guessing there is something about that templated inheritance that doesn't play well with the lambda?

Any help getting a handle on this stuff would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: What's the signature of `Stepper::step()` ?

Comment: What happens if you replace the entire `GroupStepper::step` function with `void step() { Stepper::step(objs_[0], h_); }`?

Comment: Support for lambdas was new in GCC 4.5, it wouldn't surprise me if there's a bug when parsing this code. You should try the suggestion in the comment above and could also try calling `this->Stepper::step(...)`

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps - It compiles fine without the parallel_for (and/or lambda expression).  A regular for loop works just fine.  I'll try the old method for creating functors with parallel_for now.

Comment: @JonathanWakely No I've tried that.

Comment: @MikeC bool step (obj_ptr obj, scalar h)

Comment: isn't it just about capturing `this`? Probably call from the lambda should look like `Stepper::step(this, this->objs_[i], this->h_);`?

Comment: sounds like it's a broken compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775537/data-condition-wait-invalid-argument-error

Comment: "*Compiling with gcc v. 4.5.1*" You should have known what your problem was right here... ;-]

Answer (score 0):

I think the lambda introducer (aka the capture clause) is incorrect. I don't quite see what you are trying to express by using "[this]". Have a look at the following article for the correct syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx
Hope this helps! :)